# What does しょーもなさ mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to translate this [blog](https://lineblog.me/nagatatakato/archives/954526.html).

The blogger said his today's content will be **しょーもない**.

Based on [goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/dialect/2109/m0u/), it seems to be an Osaka dialect meaning silly, stupid or lame.

> 今日の内容はとても**しょーもない**事なので、、、
>
> あんまり期待して読まないでください。
>
> え、いつもしょーもないじゃんと思ってる人
>
> 逆に読んでください。そしてその**しょーもなさ**に驚愕し恐怖を覚え僕を恐れてください、、、

However, he later said **しょーもなさ**, which I'm not sure whether it has the same meaning with **しょーもない**.

It also seems to have a hashtag on [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95/).

Answer (score 5):

First, 「しょーもない」 with the small ょ is the colloquial pronunciation of 「しようもない」 with the regular-size よ.  In kanji, しよう = 仕様.

It means "***dullsville***", "***small-time***", "***very boring***", etc.  It is an ***adjective***.

「しょーもな**さ**」 is the ***noun*** form of 「しょうもな**い**」.  You must have seen this 「さ」 in words, such as 「高{たか}さ」、「良{よ}さ」、「うまさ」, etc.  The 「さ」 turns an adjective into a noun.

So, the noun form means "***boringness***", "***small-timeness***", "***triviality***", etc.